# Which protocol should i use for Raspberry Pi communication?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, mqtt

i am making underwater vehicle that includes Raspberry Pi. I want to control it from above water with another Raspberry Pi. Data flow between two Raspberry Pi includes controlling values from above water to underwater, video stream and sensor values from underwater to above water.

I tried TCP, UDP with "import socket", i tried websockets, socket.io and now i am trying MQTT. But i could not decide which one is suitable for this project.

Comment: This question is far too broad to work on Stack Overflow. Please read the guide to asking good Stack Overflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago i was working in a project to control remotely a drone using a raspberry, UDP to send messages between raspberry and drone, and TCP/IP between raspberry and a remotely server, we manage the video streaming using RTCP and RTC. With this protocols everything works fine, there was a delay with the video streaming, but with our requirements was enough, i can recommend you to test some protocols for the video streaming, that's the critical part (it was in our case). Hope my experience can help you to find the best protocol for your project